# spread background pattern over two divs css

Tags: html, css, web

I'm currently designing a site and I'm trying to use a patterned background over two s... The issue is that everytime the window is resized, or a different resolution is used to my development one, the patterns don't align. Been looking for solutions everywhere... can't find anything. Here's a screenshot of what I mean:

http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/1056/33l3.jpg

I know you can set the background position, but that doesn't help, because when you resize the window again, because the main section and the rectangle on the top are different divs, the background moves again. Is this possible to fix? Or do I need to consider something else entirely?

Comment: I think the method you are using is going to give you a lot of trouble.  There's probably a much simpler way of doing it.  Why are you using 2 divs?  Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: why don't you put the patterned background in its own (single) `<div>` and then use child `<div>`s for the rest of the content?

Comment: Pretty much impossible. If you think about it logically, to share the SAME bg image the two divs would need to have a common parent with that bg image applied. BUT the inner div (the one moved up) would  need a transparent background and if you do that the patterned bg of the 'header div would show through instead of the striped image. Does that make sense?